# Redux returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently doing a MERN App, it's like a TODO list, but quite big

The thing is that I'm using redux thunk, with my actions, I'm sending data to the DB, and the DB returns me data and I save it in my redux, the problem is that, when I ask for the data that is saved in the reducer, it returns me an undefined, if I ask for the state, it returns me an object with the data, but if I asked for the `state.all` ( that is the array with my data ) it returns me undefined.

Where I create my store

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import { reducers } from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The actions

```js
import * as api from "../api/rooms";

export const gettingRooms = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.getAllRooms();
console.log(data)
    dispatch({ type: "ROOMS", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const creatingAll = room => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.creatingRooms(room);

    dispatch({ type: "CREATING", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

My reducer

```js
const rooms = (all = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ROOMS":
      return action.payload;

    case "CREATING":
      return [...all, action.payload];

    case "DELETE":
      return all.filter(room => action.payload._id !== room._id);

    default:
      return all;
  }
};

export default rooms;
```

Where i combine my reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import Rooms from "./rooms";

export const reducers = combineReducers({ Rooms });
```

Where I ask the DB for the information to save

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Room from "./components/rooms/Room";

// Calling Actions

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { gettingRooms } from "./actions/rooms";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(gettingRooms());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Room />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Where it returns me undefined ( the useSelector thing )

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import {
  MainBackground,
  Container,
  ShowForm,
  CreateRoom,
  Start,
  Cancel,
  Rooms,
  RoomsButtons,
  RoomsButtonEdit,
  RoomsButtonDelete
} from "./RoomStyled";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { creatingAll } from "../../actions/rooms";

const Room = () => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [showRooms, setShowRooms] = useState(false);
  const [roomData, setRoomData] = useState({ room: "" });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Asking For The Data

  const fuck = useSelector(state => state.all);

  console.log(fuck);

  // Sending The Data

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(creatingAll(roomData));

    // Showing The Room And Hiding The Form
    setShowRooms(true);
    setShowForm(false);
  };

  return (
    <MainBackground>
      <Container>
        {/* Showing The Rooms */}
        {showRooms && (
          <>
            {fuck &&
              fuck.map(room => {
                return (
                  <Rooms key={room._id}>
                    <section>
                      <div>
                        <h2>{room.room}</h2>
                      </div>

                      <RoomsButtons>
                        <span>
                          {" "}
                          <RoomsButtonEdit />{" "}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          {" "}
                          <RoomsButtonDelete />
                        </span>
                      </RoomsButtons>
                    </section>
                  </Rooms>
                );
              })}
          </>
        )}
        {/* Creating Rooms */}
        {!showForm ? (
          <ShowForm onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}>Create</ShowForm>
        ) : (
          <CreateRoom onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <section>
              <h2>Create Your Room</h2>
              <input
                name="room"
                required
                type="text"
                value={roomData.room}
                onChange={e =>
                  setRoomData({ ...roomData, room: e.target.value })
                }
                placeholder="Example : What i will do every single day in february"
                maxLength="85"
              />
              <div>
                <Start type="submit">Start</Start>
                <Cancel onClick={() => setShowForm(false)}>Cancel</Cancel>
              </div>
            </section>
          </CreateRoom>
        )}
      </Container>
    </MainBackground>
  );
};

export default Room;
```

If you notice a way to get me the array instead of the undefined, i will love you :/

Comment: Do you use combineReducers ? Can you show your reducers/index.js?

Comment: It seems there is no `all` object in the `state`. Instead of selecting `useSelector(state => state.all)`, try to select `useSelector(state => state)`.

Comment: Yes, i'm usign combineReducers, i'm gonna show you that part, i apologize !

And if i try to select only the state, that's going to return me only an object so i won't be able to use .map, because it's not an array it's an objct